# How to plot frequency distribution using seaborn in python/pandas for a bipartite text based graph data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with 70k rows, & it looks like this:

```
mirna   gene_id
osa-miR2873a    Os01g0100100
osa-miR169d Os01g0100100
osa-miR169a Os01g0100100
osa-miR396a-3p  Os01g0100200
osa-miR396b-3p  Os01g0100200
...             ...
```

I am using matplotlib & seaborn for plotting the data.
& I have managed to calculate the frequency using the `value_counts()` pandas function.

I need to plot a graph to show how many times a certain range of frequencies of 'mirna' occurences appear in the dataset. For example how many 'mirna' have 1-5 mirna-gene_id pairs, or 5-15 pairs, or 15-30 pairs & so on...

So essentially the plot should show that (1-5) pairs occur x-times, (5-15) pairs occur y-times etc.If I can plot the values in sorted order, all the more better. I have tried sns.distplot() but it is not working for me.

Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could groupby mirna and summarize by gene_id count. Then you could just do a histogram of that.